# date time in VB.NET Forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datetime

i want to save Chart image to my computer and Image name is  ChartName+Date+Time 
Ex PieChart13jan20141127.JPEG

is any format for time and date can do that  , because my format in my Code is return nothing 
my code is :

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\charts") Then
            Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{ddmmyyyy}", System.DateTime.Today)
            Chart1.SaveImage("C:\charts\PieChart" & todaysdate & ".Jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
        Else
            MsgBox("Please create Charts Folder @ C:\")
        End If
```

Comment: To produce 13jan20141127 your format string would need to be "{ddMMMyyyyHHmm}" and use DateTime.Now.

Comment: i change my code but same error  msg :  todaysdate is nothing agine  !

Comment: Matt Wilko ! before Question i just want date and now if i can have answer for date and time together !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmm")` (uppercase `MMM` for month)

```
Dim file As String = "PieChart" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmm")
Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", file, ".Jpeg")
Dim fullName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\charts", fileName)
```

I prefer `Path.Combine` to build the path since it increases readability and is less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date and time in a specific format use `DateTime.Now.ToString(aFormat)` where `aFormat` is a string of the format of date and time you require:

See here for all the formats available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx